# Errno2: No such file or directory when using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, homebrew, errno, activetcl

I downloaded ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0 for Mac (I'm running Yosemite 10.10.5) and checked that tkinter was there through terminal with `python3 -m tkinter`. I currently have 3 versions of python: 2.7.6 which came with my macbook, 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 which I installed with homebrew.

However, I keep on encountering this error when attempting to run a simple gui app:

> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'gui.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I am fairly new to Python, and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Do you supply that entire path? What do you get when you make it print `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: No, that path is created as part of the error message. My cwd is "/Users/john/Desktop/code"

Comment: Does your working directory contain a file named gui.py? How are you invoking Python?

Comment: How do you start that gui app and what is the complete error message?